How to limit the number of paths in Dijkstra algorithm in Neo4j
I hope that when using Dijkstra algorithm, the shortest path does not exceed 4 nodes. means with condition of  both path's weight and path's num for cypher。
This is my drawing neo4j command:
CREATE (c:Node {name: "liming"})
WITH [{name:"youxue-0"},{name:"youxue-1"}] AS upNode UNWIND upNode AS per CREATE (n:Node) SET n = per
CREATE (c:Node {name: "final"})
WITH [{startName: "liming", endName: "youxue-0", cost:2},{startName: "youxue-0", endName: "youxue-1", cost:2},{startName: "youxue-1", endName: "final", cost:2}] AS relationships UNWIND relationships AS rel MATCH (start:Node {name: rel.startName}), (end:Node {name: rel.endName}) CREATE (start)-[:ROAD {cost:rel.cost}]->(end)
WITH [{name:"cw-0"}] AS upNode UNWIND upNode AS per CREATE (n:Node) SET n = per
WITH [{startName: "liming", endName: "cw-0", cost:2},{startName: "cw-0", endName: "final", cost:2}] AS relationships UNWIND relationships AS rel MATCH (start:Node {name: rel.startName}), (end:Node {name: rel.endName}) CREATE (start)-[:ROAD {cost:rel.cost}]->(end)
WITH [{name:"yiyun-0"},{name:"yiyun-1"},{name:"yiyun-2"},{name:"yiyun-3"}] AS upNode UNWIND upNode AS per CREATE (n:Node) SET n = per
WITH [{startName: "liming", endName: "yiyun-0", cost:1},{startName: "yiyun-0", endName: "yiyun-1", cost:1},{startName: "yiyun-1", endName: "yiyun-2", cost:1},{startName: "yiyun-2", endName: "yiyun-3", cost:1},{startName: "yiyun-3", endName: "final", cost:1}] AS relationships UNWIND relationships AS rel MATCH (start:Node {name: rel.startName}), (end:Node {name: rel.endName}) CREATE (start)-[:ROAD {cost:rel.cost}]->(end)
WITH [{name:"rock-0"}] AS upNode UNWIND upNode AS per CREATE (n:Node) SET n = per
WITH [{startName: "liming", endName: "rock-0", cost:1},{startName: "rock-0", endName: "final", cost:1}] AS relationships UNWIND relationships AS rel MATCH (start:Node {name: rel.startName}), (end:Node {name: rel.endName}) CREATE (start)-[:ROAD {cost:rel.cost}]->(end)

this is my cypher query:
CALL gds.graph.project(
    'yoGraph',
    'Node',
    'ROAD',
    {
        relationshipProperties: 'cost'
    }
)
MATCH (source:Node {name: 'liming'}), (target:Node {name: 'final'})
CALL gds.shortestPath.yens.stream('myGraph', {
    sourceNode: source,
    targetNode: target,
    k: 3,
    relationshipWeightProperty: 'cost'
})
YIELD index, sourceNode, targetNode, totalCost, nodeIds, costs, path
WHERE SIZE(costs) < 5
RETURN
    index,
    gds.util.asNode(sourceNode).name AS sourceNodeName,
    gds.util.asNode(targetNode).name AS targetNodeName,
    totalCost,
    [nodeId IN nodeIds | gds.util.asNode(nodeId).name] AS nodeNames, 
    costs,
    nodes(path) as path

the "K" I gave 3, but only got 2 results:
╒═════╤══════════════╤══════════════╤═════════╤═════════════════════════════╤═══════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│index│sourceNodeName│targetNodeName│totalCost│nodeNames                    │costs          │path                                                                  │
╞═════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪═════════╪═════════════════════════════╪═══════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│0    │"liming"      │"final"       │2.0      │["liming", "rock-0", "final"]│[0.0, 1.0, 2.0]│[(:Node {name: "liming"}), (:Node {name: "rock-0"}), (:Node {name: "fi│
│     │              │              │         │                             │               │nal"})]                                                               │
├─────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼─────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│1    │"liming"      │"final"       │4.0      │["liming", "cw-0", "final"]  │[0.0, 2.0, 4.0]│[(:Node {name: "liming"}), (:Node {name: "cw-0"}), (:Node {name: "fina│
│     │              │              │         │                             │               │l"})]                                                                 │
└─────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴─────────┴─────────────────────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

I think the WHERE condition works in the result set. I hope result like this:
╒═════╤══════════════╤══════════════╤═════════╤═══════════════════════════════════════════╤════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│index│sourceNodeName│targetNodeName│totalCost│nodeNames                                  │costs               │path                                                                  │
╞═════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪═════════╪═══════════════════════════════════════════╪════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│0    │"liming"      │"final"       │2.0      │["liming", "rock-0", "final"]              │[0.0, 1.0, 2.0]     │[(:Node {name: "liming"}), (:Node {name: "rock-0"}), (:Node {name: "fi│
│     │              │              │         │                                           │                    │nal"})]                                                               │
├─────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│1    │"liming"      │"final"       │4.0      │["liming", "cw-0", "final"]                │[0.0, 2.0, 4.0]     │[(:Node {name: "liming"}), (:Node {name: "cw-0"}), (:Node {name: "fina│
│     │              │              │         │                                           │                    │l"})]                                                                 │
├─────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│3    │"liming"      │"final"       │6.0      │["liming", "youxue-0", "youxue-1", "final"]│[0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0]│[(:Node {name: "liming"}), (:Node {name: "youxue-0"}), (:Node {name: "│
│     │              │              │         │                                           │                    │youxue-1"}), (:Node {name: "final"})]                                 │
└─────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴─────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Is there any suggestion?

this cypher solve my problem.
MATCH (start:Node {name: "liming"}), (end:Node {name: "final"})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(start, {
    relationshipFilter: "ROAD",
    minLevel: 1,
    maxLevel: 4,
    endNodes: [end]
})
YIELD path 
WITH path, nodes(path) AS nodelist
WHERE nodelist[-2].name <> "nihao"
WITH path, REDUCE(s = 0, rel IN relationships(path) | s + rel.cost) AS totalWeight
ORDER BY totalWeight ASC
LIMIT 3
RETURN path, totalWeight

and also filter the second last node‘s property
